# How to redirect app in Android Emulator to development notebook?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I develop a multiplatform (browser, Android, later iOS) and multiplayer word game and mostly do it on my old Macbook Air, but also sometimes on a Windows 7 PC:

[image: Macbook screenshot]

While developing the HTML5 part of my game it was very comfortable to run the browser at my Macbook and make it connect to localhost, where the development version of my game backend was running: Jetty + PostgreSQL.

However now I have completed the browser part of my game and have switched to Android development.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a good way to redirect HTTP and WebSocket connections from my app running in Android Emulator to the "development backend" running at the same Macbook. And thus I have to use my "production backend" for testing (which is uncomfortable and requires good internet connectivity).

Please share your tricks and strategies for doing such a development, I am sure most of you had to work on an Android app + some HTTP script.

I was thinking of using dnsmasq (through "brew"), but haven't found a good way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple solution to my problem, which would even work while on a plane (with no connectivity) -

The address http://10.0.2.2 entered in Android Emulator would point to my notebook as described in the doc [Set Up Android Emulator Networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html):

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively I got suggestions to take a look at `adb reverse` or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com)